# Short circuit operator for JSF(P) EL

Tags: java, jsf, el, short-circuiting

Are there short circuit operators for Expression Language used in JSF, JSP?

I mean  `&&`,`||` Java analog,when if it's obvious that further evaluation of boolean has no sense, that evaluation is stopped.

I observed usage of `and`, `or` operators  and looks like they're not short circuit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It are definitely short circuit operators.

```
#{bean.left or bean.right}
```

The right hand won't be evaluated when the left hand evaluates true.

```
#{bean.left and bean.right}
```

The right hand won't be evaluated when the left hand evaluates false.